# error when try to config sub domain in laravel 5

Tags: laravel

I have problem when try to config sub domain for host.For example:
my host is: `demo.com` and I want to config `demo.com/speech`.
File route is something like this :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'speech', 'as' => 'speech'], function()
{
    Route::resource('user', 'UserController', ['as' => 'speech.user']);
});
```

and in file `blade` following syntax:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => ['speech.user.update',$user->user_id ], 'method' => 'PATCH', 'files'=> true)) !!}
```

This code show error: `Route [speech.user.update] not defined.`
What can I do, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solutions is:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'speech'], function()
{
    Route::resource('user', 'UserController', [ 'names' => [
        'index'   => 'speech.user.index',
        'create'  => 'speech.user.create',
        'store'   => 'speech.user.store',
        'show'    => 'speech.user.show',
        'edit'    => 'speech.user.edit',
        'update'  => 'speech.user.update',
        'destroy' => 'speech.user.destroy',
    ]]);
}
```

and in file blade i call route following syntax: `route('speech.user.edit',$speech->user_id)`
It's working for me

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'speech', 'as' => 'speech'], function()
{
    Route::resource('user', 'UserController', ['as' => 'user']);
});
```

With your current route group you have to access it this way:

```
speech.speech.user.update
```

You can also verify named routes on terminal

```
php artisan route:list
```